# In Yii2 is there any relationship between Namespaces naming conventions and folders they reside in?

Tags: php, namespaces, yii2

For example there is a namespace like `yii\console` and `yii\console\controllers`. In `yii\console` all the .php files are defined by `namespace yii\console;` same as the .php files in `yii\console\controllers` being defined with `namespace yii\console\controllers;`

Does this mean php namespace functions and classes can be located in multiple files as the same namespace? Are the namespaces defined by their location on the application or is this just a Yii convention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this mean php namespace functions and classes can be located in multiple files as the same namespace?

If functions are methods, they are not directly related to a namespace but to the class belonging to the namespace.

> Are the namespaces defined by their location on the application or is this just a Yii convention?

It's not really an `YII` convention, other frameworks (symfony, zend, laravel, cakephp etc.) are also working (more or less) this way.
This `path` <=> `namespace` relations are usually defined by an [`autoloader`](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md#closure-example).

See namespaces examples from the [PSR-4](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader.md#3-examples).

You should read [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php). [php-fig](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/tree/master/accepted) might help you to understand why and how namespaces are used in general.

Comment: I have gone through a lot of documents including the one you sent. I just needed a more precise/direct answer to my question. Another thing I need to know, you say it is used by other frameworks too but what I really meant is, is it required by PHP itself? For example when I define namespaces without using a framework, should I define it according to folder location?

Comment: No it must not be related to a path but if not I think it's loosing the namespace interest.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, you have answered what I needed clarification with on the comment. For anyone with the same issue I would recommend reading (http://www.sitepoint.com/php-53-namespaces-basics/) . That really explained to me in the easiest way.